# Selecionar Checkbox e habilitar campos no Android

Tags: android, checkbox

Estou usando checkbox e um edittext. Quando a aplicação inicia, o edittext é desabilitado. Quando o usuário marca a caixa do checkbox, o campo edittext habilita.

Estou com problema para habilitar. Já coloquei no OnCreate mais ele não reconhece o click quando seleciono o checkbox.

```
 private void escolhaCheckbox(){

    if (arvorismoInfantil.isChecked()){
        edt_arvorismoInfantil.setEnabled(true);
        int valorArvorismo = Integer.valueOf(edt_arvorismoInfantil.getText().toString());
        int total;
        total = valorArvorismo * 4;
        Log.i("total", String.valueOf(total));
    }
}
```

E no metódo `onCreate`

```
 edt_arvorismoInfantil.setEnabled(false);
 escolhaCheckbox();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use o `setOnCheckedChangeListener` no seu `CheckBox`. Desta forma abaixo:

```
arvorismoInfantil.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // aqui você habilita seu edittext usando o isChecked
    }
});
```

Comment: muito obrigado, era isso mesmo. Deu certinho aqui no que implementei .